# Parent property is not bind to the child (Ember 2.8)

Tags: ember.js, data-binding

My code:

signup.emblem:

```
= validating-form onsubmit=(action 'signUp')
  = input-field value=username
  span {{usernameError}}
```

validating-form.js:

```
submit(event) {
  console.log(this.get('username') //undefined
  this.sendAction('onsubmit')
}
```

signup.js:

```
actions: {
    signUp() {      
      console.log(this.get('username')) // value from input
    }
  }
```

As you can see the basic idea is some value in input gets validated in validating-form component and then if everything is fine it'll call some controller action or set some properties.

The problem is that apparently this form component isn't bind to properties from controller, even though its child component (input-field) is. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here?

If I have to bind it explicitely, is there some way to do that with multiple properties at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the standard input element isn't two-way bound to your `username` variable.  You can bind it quickly using the `action` and `mut` helpers.

(example in handlebars, but you should be able to convert to emblem easily enough)

```
<input value={{username}} onblur={{action (mut username) value='target.value'}}>
```

This is saying:

- on the onblur event
- mut(ate) the username
- to match the current `target.value` - which is the value of the input box

You can see evidence of this working in this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/53096495c449783ef196ad51c7632d00?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

The other option is [Input Helpers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/templates/input-helpers/)

I've not used these, as they don't follow the current Ember thinking of Data Down Actions Up, but it should be as simple as:

```
{{input value=username}}
```

And this will two-way-bind directly username.

Comment: In my input-field component I am already using input helper which enables two-way binding. It works fine in `login` controller, then breaks in `validating-form` (component overrides it for its own usage), then works fine again in `input-field`.

Comment: Okay, i suspect what is happening is that as the variables are mixed between components and controllers, the variable is not going to exist in both places.  If the form is in a component, and you to call the validation function in a controller, then you will need to pass the validation function into the component.

Comment: I thought controllers are also components. But I was wrong.